# Can't send message within socket chat room

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When I try to send a message within a room I get this `TypeError: Cannot read property roomClients' of undefined`,
node.js and working with sockets is new to me, so the fix might be simple.

Any idea to what causes the error? I really appreciate any suggestions

Here is the server-side code:

```js
// Setting up the server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var Room = require('./room.js');
var _ = require('underscore')._;
var uuid = require ('uuid');
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running...');

socket.set("log level", 1);
var people = {};  
var rooms = {};
var clients = [];

Array.prototype.contains = function(k, callback) {  
    var self = this;
    return (function check(i) {
        if (i >= self.length) {
            return callback(false);
        }
        if (self[i] === k) {
            return callback(true);
        }
        return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i+1));
    }(0));
};



// Gets the html file
app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

// Gets the css file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// When connecting
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
 client.on("join", function(name){
  console.log("Someone joined the chat", name);
  roomID = null;
  people[client.id] = {"name" : name, "room" : roomID};
  sizePeople = _.size(people);
  sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
  socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
  socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
  client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have connected to the server. Join or create room to chat");
  

  client.broadcast.emit('updateToOthers', name + " is online.");
  //client.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms});
  clients.push(client); //populate the clients array with the client object
 });

//Creating room
 client.on("serverCreateNewRoom", function(name){
  console.log("About to create a room", name)
  if (people[client.id].room === null) {
   console.log("First time creating a room")
   var id = uuid.v4();
   var room = new Room(name, id, client.id);
   rooms[id] = room;
   sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
   socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms}); //update the list of rooms on the frontend
   client.room = name; //name the room
   client.join(client.room); //auto-join the creator to the room
   room.addPerson(client.id); //also add the person to the room object
   people[client.id].room = id; //Update the room key with the ID of the created room
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have created a room");
  } else {
   socket.sockets.emit("updateToSelf", "You have already created a room");
  }
 });

//joining room
 client.on("joinRoom", function(id) {
  console.log("Someone is trying to join a room")
  var room = rooms[id];
  if (client.id === room.owner) {
   client.emit("updateToSelf", "You are the owner of this room and you have already been joined.");
   console.log("Owner is trying to join own room");
  } else {
   room.people.contains(client.id, function(found) {
    if (found) {
     client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have already joined this room.");
    } else {
     if (people[client.id].inroom !== null) { //make sure that one person joins one room at a time
      client.emit("updateToSelf", "You are already in a room ("+rooms[people[client.id].inroom].name+"), please leave it first to join another room.");
      console.log("User is already in the room");
     } else {
      room.addPerson(client.id);
      people[client.id].inroom = id;
      client.room = room.name;
      client.join(client.room); //add person to the room
      user = people[client.id];
      socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("updateToOthers", user.name + " has connected to " + room.name + " room.");
      client.emit("update", "Welcome to " + room.name + ".");
       client.emit("sendRoomID", {id: id});
     }
    }
   });
  }
 });




// When sending
 client.on("send message", function(msg){
  if (socket.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]['/'+socket.room] !== undefined) {
   socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("chat", people[client.id], msg);
   //client.emit("ownMessage", msg);
   //client.broadcast.emit('newMessageToOthers', people[client.id], msg);
  console.log("Message send", msg);
  } else {
   client("updateToSelf", "Please connect to a room");
  }  
 });



});
```

Comment: socket.sockets.manager does not exists. Take a look at your **sockets** object.

Comment: Server-side is really new to me, so could you maybe give me an example of how I can add it?

Comment: 1. Where did you get this code example? - There might be full example. Cause this code is incomplete

2. You can add breakpoint to line that you need to inspect what it does.

Comment: Got it here: http://www.tamas.io/advanced-chat-using-node-js-and-socket-io-episode-1/

Comment: Great! Then you can use full code from those article: https://github.com/tpiros/advanced-chat

Comment: I have already looked through that code. However, as I'm new to server-side, I can't tell what I'm missing. The full code also involves functions that I'm yet to implement. Right now I'm following the guide, which doesn't involve the same number of functions as the full code

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't enough experience with node.js (please add tag to your question) to suggest you solution. Anyway you have to try provided example first. Then you have to edit those code step by step to see what's goin on. Also you might want to look websockets: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications

 Best regards